# How can I make a graph that compares two sequences

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have two data sets.

I produce the first one from the following code:

```
Clear[x, T, a, b]
T[x_] := T[x] = 
   Piecewise[{{1 - x, 0 <= x < 1/7}, {(x + 6)/7, 1/7 <= x <= 1}}]
a[n_] := a[n] = n/(n + 1)
b[n_] := b[n] = n/(n + 5)
x[0] = 0.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = 
   T[(1 - a[n - 1])* T[x[n - 1]] + 
     a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1]) x[n - 1] + b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]]]
Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

The second one is produce this code:

```
Clear[x, T, a, b]
T[x_] := T[x] = 
   Piecewise[{{1 - x, 0 <= x < 1/7}, {(x + 6)/7, 1/7 <= x <= 1}}]
a[n_] := a[n] = n/(n + 1)
b[n_] := b[n] = n/(n + 5)
x[0] = 0.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = 
   (1 - a[n - 1])* T[x[n - 1]] + 
     a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1]) *x[n - 1] + b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]]
Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

I want to draw a beautiful comparative graph. Let the first sequence generated by first code be sequence M and the sequence generated by second code be K.

Any help?

Comment: You should put your code in code blocks. The functions that you posted are identical. Either explain what you mean by comparative graph and M and K functions or link to a description.

Comment: can I suggest if you actually have two different functions you get creative and give them different names?  You should never use capital letters to start your own function names by the way.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon The function are identical but original sequence will b generated due the function x[n], which are different. two sequences will be generated. for each iteration the previous value is the domain value.

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for suggestions

Comment: simply assign each of your tables to a variable (say `k` and `m` ) and do `ListPlot[{k, m}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's first refactor your code to simplify it. Note I am removing the memoization of `T`, `a`, and `b`, because I don't think you gain much from memoization of these functions. You can easily restore it if you think I've misjudged the situation.

```
T[x_] := Piecewise[{{1 - x, 0 <= x < 1/7}, {(x + 6)/7, 1/7 <= x <= 1}}]
a[n_] := n/(n + 1)
b[n_] := n/(n + 5)

m =
  Module[{x},
    x[0] = 0.9; 
    x[n_] := x[n] = 
      T[(1 - a[n - 1])*T[x[n - 1]] + a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1]) x[n - 1] +
        b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]]];
    Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}]]
```

> `{0.9, 0.997959, 0.999961, 0.999999, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}`

```
k =
  Module[{x},
    x[0] = 0.9; 
    x[n_] := x[n] = 
      (1 - a[n - 1])*T[x[n - 1]] + a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1])*x[n - 1] + 
        b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]];
    Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}]]
```

> `{0.9, 0.985714, 0.998105, 0.999773, 0.999975, 0.999998, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}`

Now the plot.

```
ListPlot[{m, k},
  PlotMarkers -> 
    {Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[.03]]}], 
     Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[.018]]}]},
  DataRange -> {0, 10},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Here is a somewhat fancier version of the plot with a nice legend.

```
With[{
    redMkr = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[.03]]}], 
    bluMkr = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[.018]]}],
    legend =
      SwatchLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"M", "K"}, 
        LegendMarkers -> Graphics[{Opacity[1], Rectangle[]}], 
        LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
        LegendMargins -> 5]},
  ListPlot[{m, k},
    DataRange -> {0, 10},
    PlotMarkers -> {redMkr, bluMkr},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
    PlotLegends -> legend]]
```

[image: fancy]

Comment: Thank you very much. If we need graphic representation instead of ploting, then what will be needed in code??? and Sir is 1. is exact value?

Comment: @Marwat. 1. is an inexact value. As to a graphic representation that is not a plot, I don't understand what distinction you are making.

Comment: I means from graph the attached line...

Comment: From graph I means the attached line...

Comment: @Marwat. Try adding the option `Joined -> True` to the plot. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Maybe he means Filling->{1->{2}}

Comment: @m_goldberg yes it works